# Accessing/saving data in pivot table (through / habtm)

Tags: cakephp, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3 (what I'm new to), I want to realize a acl-system. I got Tables like `Users`, `Modules`, `Groups`. One `User` can be a member of many `Groups`. One `Module` can be assigned to many `Groups`. Based on the `Group`, the `Use`r has some rights on a `module` (like read/write/execute). These pieces of information are saved in the Table `groups_modules`. It looks like this:

```
module_id | INT
groupd_id | INT
execute | BOOLEAN
read | BOOLEAN
write | BOOLEAN
update | BOOLEAN
delete | BOOLEAN
```

I baked all my MVC, added new `Users`, `Modules` and `Groups` - all data have been saved. But nowhere I can enter my access-rights.

So I read the manual "http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option", I followed these instructions, but they seem to be incomplete. Of course, I need to adapt my view to show input-fields for the rights.

**The main problem is**, that I don't get all the coherences regarding this problem/topic.

Please, can someone please explain me, what I have to do.

Comment: So, have you also read **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-additional-data-to-the-joint-table**?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I understand what they mean by this, but I don't know the whole context. Therefore I asked for one complete and simple example.

Comment: Hello, can somebody give me a short example please. I haven't solved this problem yet. Only a short code ;) Thanks!